# How to tell if I am about to run Hadoop streaming job on a cluster or in "local" mode?

Tags: hadoop, local, cluster-computing, hadoop-streaming

Hadoop streaming will run the process in "local" mode when there is no hadoop instance running on the box.  I have a shell script that is controlling a set of hadoop streaming jobs in sequence and I need to condition copying files from HDFS to local depending on whether the jobs have been running locally or not.  Is there a standard way to accomplish this test? I could do a "ps aux | grep something" but that seems ad-hoc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than trying to detect at run time which mode the process is operating, it is probably better to wrap the tool you are developing in a bash script that explicitly selects local vs cluster operatide.  The O'Reilly Hadoop describes how to explicitly choose local using a configuration file override:

```
hadoop v2.MaxTemperatureDriver -conf conf/hadoop-local.xml input/ncdc/micro max-temp
```

where `conf-local.xml` is an XML file configured for local operation.

Answer (score 0):

> Hadoop streaming will run the process in "local" mode when there is no hadoop instance running on the box.

Can you pl point to the reference for this?

A regular or a streaming job will run the way it is configured, so we know ahead of time in which mode a Job is run. Check the documentation for configuring Hadoop on a [Single Node](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.22.0/single_node_setup.html) and [Cluster](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r0.22.0/cluster_setup.html) in different modes.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this yet, but I think you can just read out the mapred.job.tracker configuration setting.